# How to debug a MetacelloProjectSpecLoadError?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, metacello

When loading a configuration which depends of many configurations I have a debugger windows opened with:

```
MetacelloProjectSpecLoadError: 
No version found for '13' of ConfigurationOfNeoCSV because: Version '13' is not defined in ConfigurationOfNeoCSV. 
Possible versions include: #(#bleedingEdge #stable '1-baseline' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10' '11' '12')
```

I don't know which configuration is having problems with this dependency. Has anybody found a way to query which Metacello projects depends on a configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct solution, but once you get that error you'll already have loaded the problematic configuration. So what you can do is to search for all the method strings which contain `NeoCSV`[1] and then look at the version number used there. You should then be able to change the version number to 12 and simply reevaluate the load statement (the change in the configuration will not be overridden if I'm not mistaken).

Please report the configuration this concerns, so we can fix it.

[1] write the string in a playground (without quotes), select the text, right click on it, select "code search" -> "advanced string search".

Comment: I did what you suggested and found a way to patch the configuration, but I expected a way to query metacello configurations given the Smalltalk maturity and very rich history on reflection.

Comment: I understand that. But I don't know of any method (although there may be one).

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug in the configuration of NeoCSV. We'll fix it

Comment: Ok, Sven committed a fix